# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{a+\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I need to show that 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{a+\cos(x)}dx = 2\pi \left(1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right), a >1$$
 I am unsure where to start. I tried using the methods described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution,

but not sure which substitutions to use. I would like to use residue calculus, but not sure which contour would work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As often happens here, "solve" is the wrong word. One _solves_ equations; one _solves_ problems. One _evalutates_ expressions.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\cos x &= \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} \\ {} \\
dx &= \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\,dt.
\end{align}
$$
Why is there any difficulty in knowing which substitutions to use. The cosine appears here and the sine does not. $\qquad$

Comment: For residue calculus use the substitution  $z=e^{ix} $.

Comment: "not sure which substitutions to use": the link describes a *single* substitution, no hesitation.

Comment: By what you write, I see it is assumed $\;|a|\ge1\;$ ...

Comment: I am sorry if i formulated my question wrong, but it seems to obvious to me that i am not referring to the substitutions of cos(x), sin(x) used in the article, but any other substitutions that can be used to simplify the integral. I can get it on the form \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{a+\cos(x)}dx &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)}{a+\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)} \frac{2}{1+t^2} dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2(1-t^2)}{(a(1+t^2)+1-t^2)(1+t^2)} dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{a}{(a-1)t^2+a+1}-\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right) dt
\end{align*}, but unsure after

Comment: To expand on the residue calculus approach, we have $\cos x=(z+1/z)/2$ with $z=e^{ix}$ and since the contour is the unit circle we have \begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x}{a+\cos x}\,dx&=1-a\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{a+\cos x}=1-a\int_C\frac{dz/iz}{a+(z+1/z)/2}\\&=1+2ai\int_C\frac{dz}{z^2+2az+1}.\end{align} Now determine the poles that lie inside $C$.

Comment: @zucian You haven't changed the limits. The second of your integral is the arctangent, and for the first divide by $a+1$, for $|a| \ne 1$ and then let $t = \sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}y$. It too will become the standard arctangent.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x}{a+\cos x}dx=
2\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(1-\frac{a}{a+\cos x}\right)dx=2\pi - 2a \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a+\cos x}
$$

Use the half-angle substitution $t = \tan\frac x2$, $\cos x =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $dx = \frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$ to evaluate the integral,

$$I=2\pi - 2a \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2dt}{(a+1)+(a-1)t^2}$$
$$=2\pi - \frac{4a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}t}{1+\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}t \right)^2}$$
$$=2\pi - \frac{4a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\tan^{-1} \sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}t \bigg|_0^{\infty}
=2\pi \left(1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use complex analysis.

$\cos x = \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$

$\int \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2a+e^{ix} + e^{-ix}} dx$

$z = e^{ix}, dx = \frac{1}{iz} \ dz$

This is going to make your contour be the unit circle.

$\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac {z + z^{-1}}{iz(2a+z + z^{-1})} dz\\
\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac {z^2 + 1}{iz(z^2 + 2az + 1)} dz$

The roots of the denominator (the poles of the function) are

$0, -a+\sqrt{a^2-1},-a-\sqrt{a^2-1}$

but $-a-\sqrt{a^2-1}$ is not inside the contour so we can ignore it.  We have just the two residues to find.

$2\pi (1 + \frac {(-a+ \sqrt {a^2-1}) + (-a + \sqrt {a^2-1})^{-1}}{2\sqrt {a^2-1}})\\
2\pi (1 + \frac {-2a}{2\sqrt {a^2-1}})$